# Why do ConcurrentModificationException on a Java Set dump Stack Trace about Map iterator?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, set, concurrentmodification

If I concurrently modify a Java Set, I'll get a ConcurrentModificationException. The problem is that the stack trace suggests the modification was encountered on a certain Map iterator. I now understand that Maps are used to implement Sets in java but these details are internal to the implementation. I believe the internal Map iterator Exception should have been properly wrapped inside a Set Iterator related exception that should have been passed back.

Am I making sense or am I missing something? I just spent two days trying to find the non-existent faulty Map operation in the code only to ultimately stumble upon (zooming in through trial and error, not by a logical process or documentation) on the Set operation that was causing the problem. I am wondering how I can avoid such frustrations in future.

-----------UPDATE--------------
My query is not about how to get the concurrency right. My query is how to avoid getting misguided by such unhelpful stack trace messages. A Map Iterator exception has no business showing up in the stack traces instead of the actual SetIterator exception which makes sense from the user's perspective

Answer (score 1):

While it may look a little odd on the surface, when you get such an error the stack trace should give you the information you need - ignore the first few lines of the trace which are internal to `java.util` and look for the first reference to one of your own classes. This line will be the place to start looking when you debug.

As for why the iterator over a `HashSet` appears to be a map-related rather than a set-related type, this is because it *is* - the implementation of `HashSet.iterator` simply returns `backingMap.keySet().iterator()`. There is no "SetIterator" as such.

Comment: Well, what I mean is there should be one more trace-step in the stack trace; something like:
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:845)
*** at java.util.HashSet$HashIterator.next(HashSet.java:###) ***
at sample.learning.SetIterationExample.main(ListGetterIteration.java:25)

Or may be the HashMap exception should have been traced as a cause pof the exception (the getCause() on our exception here returned null), not as the location of the exception?
I have been advised to take the line numbers witha pinch of salt (especially in failfast/best effort behavior exceptions)

Comment: the name of the iterator on the Set doesn't matter as long as it is associated with the Set here in question

Comment: @SatyanRaina That would require a whole extra wrapper class to be written and would introduce another layer of method calls for no reason.  The backing map's `keySet().iterator()` obeys all the conditions for an iterator over the `HashSet` contents, so it makes perfect sense to use it.  When you read down the stack trace and find out where _your_ code first calls into `java.util` you'll see immediately which iterator you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

A ConcurrentModificationException occurs when a collection is being iterated through, and another thread attempts to modify it; or vice-versa. I understand your point, but an easy way around this is simply to have a boolean flag indicating the collection is being iterated through. That way your modification thread can simply wait for that flag to go false, and your threads will never have a clash like that :)

Comment: Chris, I understand why the exception is thrown. My concern is that the stack-trace associates the exception with a Map iterator, not a Set iterator because internally Sets are implemented using Maps in java. My Question is how to avoid such misdirections caused by such stack traces

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Set that allows for concurrent modification. Like ConcurrentSkipListSet or CopyOnWriteArraySet alternatively Google Guava has additional ways for getting concurrent sets.